# Изменение класса родителя в зависимости от кол-ва определённых дочерних элементов через JS

Tags: javascript

У нас есть код:

```
  <dl class="contacts details">
    <h3 class="contacts">Contacts:</h3>
    <a class="Website Icons" href="https://test.com/"></a>
    <a class="Kik Icons" href="https://www.kik.me/test"></a>
    <a class="Snap Icons" href="https://www.snapchat.com/add/test"></a>
    <a class="Telegram Icons" href="https://t.me/test"></a>
  </dl>
```

Что нужно?

Добавить класс к `<dl class="contacts details">` в зависимости от количества `<a>` внутри, например,
если один `<a>`, то `<dl class="contacts details one">`,
если два `<a>`, то `<dl class="contacts details two">`,
если три `<a>`, то `<dl class="contacts details three">` и так до шести.

Всем безумно благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Почему именно имена классов? На что они в дальнейшем влияют?

Comment: И с чем именно возникли проблемы? Количество элементов не умеете считать? Или как обратиться к элементу с классом `contacts`? Или не знаете как добавить класс к элементу? Или не знаете как в зависимости от количества добавить конкретный класс?

Comment: в дальнейшем каждому классу задаются нужные значения в css, влияет на их позиционрование, проблема в том, что я не знаю js

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Динамический отступ через JS в зависимости от кол-ва дочерних элементов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1471866/%d0%94%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-js-%d0%b2-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%85-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: А почему нельзя сразу определить стили CSS в зависимости от количества дочерних элементов, например как показано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12198561/3129992)?

Answer (score -2):

```
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.details')
const length = wrapper.querySelectorAll('a').length

length === 1
  ? wrapper.classList.add('one')
  : length === 2
    ? wrapper.classList.add('two')
    : length === 3
      ? wrapper.classList.add('three')
      : ...
```

далее по аналогии. можно сделать проще, добавляя какой-нибудь класс типа `length1` - `length6`

```
const wrapper = document.querySelector('.details')
const length = wrapper.querySelectorAll('a').length

wrapper.classList.add(`length${length}`)
```

Comment: Ужансые решения)) особенно представляю лестницу  к 9-му кругу ада из первого абзаца ответа, если классов будет чуть больше))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский для этого второй вариант, где все в 1 строку

Comment: А если таких классов потребуется 200 :)? Тоже вручную будете писать?

Comment: @ΝNL993 для этого второй вариант, где все в 1 строку

Comment: @Meth0d тогда это уже будет ответ не по вопросу.